# Posting form says that I didn't provide input

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I'm trying to post to a form on this page: http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl?identifier=802634%20802659&additional_network_nodes=0&chemicalmode=10.5&input_query_species=7955&interactive=yes&internal_call=1&limit=10&minprotchem=1&network_flavor=actions&required_score=400&sessionId=0ZKGxMnojGDg&targetmode=proteins&userId=Ri1Zp7hT9L9G. The form that I want to post to is (Info & Parameters ... at the bottom of the page):

```
<form action="/cgi/show_network_section.pl" id='standard_parameters' method='post'>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>Network Display -  Nodes are either colored (if they are directly linked to the input - as in the table) or white (nodes of a higher iteration/depth). Edges, i.e. predicted functional links, consist of up to eight lines: one color for each type of evidence. Hover or click to reveal more information about the node/edge. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='3'><hr/></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>Active Prediction Methods:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>
      <input name='channel1' type='checkbox' />Neighborhood       <input name='channel2' type='checkbox' />Gene Fusion       <input name='channel3' type='checkbox' />Co-occurrence <br/>      <input name='channel4' type='checkbox' />Co-expression      <input name='channel5' type='checkbox' checked='checked'/>Experiments       <input name='channel6' type='checkbox' checked='checked'/>Databases       <input name='channel7' type='checkbox' checked='checked'/>Textmining       <input name='channel8' type='checkbox' />Predictions       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">required confidence (score):</td>
      <td align='left'><img src="http://stitch.embl.de/images/small_white.png" width='70' height='5' alt=''/></td>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">interactors shown:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <select name='required_score'>
  <option  value='900'>highest confidence (0.900)</option>
  <option  value='700'>high confidence (0.700)</option>
  <option selected='selected' value='400'>medium confidence (0.400)</option>
  <option  value='150'>low confidence (0.150)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td align='left'><img src="http://stitch.embl.de/images/small_white.png" width='70' height='5' alt=''/></td>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <select name='limit'>
   <option  value='5'>no more than 5 interactors</option>
   <option selected='selected' value='10'>no more than 10 interactors</option>
   <option  value='20'>no more than 20 interactors</option>
   <option  value='50'>no more than 50 interactors</option>
         </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align='right' style="white-space:nowrap">or custom value:         <input name='custom_score' size='8' maxlength='8' /></td>
      <td align='left'><img src="http://stitch.embl.de/images/small_white.png" width='70' height='5' alt=''/></td>
      <td align='right' style="white-space:nowrap">or custom limit:         <input name='custom_limit' size='8' maxlength='8' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'><hr/></td>
    </tr>
<tr><td colspan='3'>
<table border='0'>
<tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap">additional (white) nodes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap; text-align=center;">
<input name='additional_network_nodes' onchange="UpdateNavigationButtonsFromForm (this); return true;" size='10' value='0'/>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='3'><hr/></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align='left' style="white-space:nowrap">        <input type='submit' value="Update Parameters"/></td>
      <td>
        <input name='identifier' type='hidden' value="802634 802659"/>
        <input name='required_score' type='hidden' value='400'/>
        <input name='limit' type='hidden' value='10'/>
        <input name='UserId' type='hidden' value='Ri1Zp7hT9L9G'/>
        <input name='sessionId' type='hidden' value='0ZKGxMnojGDg'/>
        <input name='network_flavor' type='hidden' value='actions'/>
        <input name='external_payload_URL' type='hidden' value='_unassigned'/>
        <input name='internal_payload_id' type='hidden' value='_unassigned'/>
        <input name='chemicalmode' type='hidden' value='10.5'/>
        <input name='input_query_species' type='hidden' value='7955'/>
        <input name='internal_call' type='hidden' value='1'/>
      </td>
      <td align='right' style='white-space:nowrap; black'>      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

with the following Python (Python 3) script:

```
# python imports. Some might have to be installed first
import urllib
import requests

# Change to the URL that you get after inputting your genes. This is before filtering for 400
stitch_results_url = 'http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl?identifier=802634%20802659&additional_network_nodes=0&chemicalmode=10.5&input_query_species=7955&interactive=yes&internal_call=1&limit=10&minprotchem=1&network_flavor=actions&required_score=400&sessionId=0ZKGxMnojGDg&targetmode=proteins&userId=Ri1Zp7hT9L9G'
# the custom limit of the interaction shown
interaction_shown_custom_limit = 400
# parameters for active prediction methods
neighborhood = 'off'
gene_fusion = 'off'
co_occurrence = 'off'
co_expression = 'off'
experiments = 'on'
databases = 'on'
textmining = 'on'
# required confidence score
required_confidence = 'high confidence (700)'

# Input parameters we are going to send
parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode({
  'channel1': neighborhood,
  'channel2': gene_fusion,
  'channel3': co_occurrence,
  'channel4': co_expression,
  'channel5': experiments,
  'channel6': databases,
  'channel7': textmining,
  'required_score':required_confidence,
  'custom_limit':interaction_shown_custom_limit
  })

parameters_payload = bytes(parameters, 'ascii')
# Build our Request object
req = requests.post(stitch_results_url, parameters_payload)
print(req.text)
```

`print(req.text)` gives me the html that I pasted at the bottom of the page. It says that no input was given. Why does it not recognize my data input?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel='SHORTCUT ICON' href='http://stitch.embl.de/images/favicon.ico' />
<title>STITCH: chemical association networks</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function loadFPWindow (node, label) {
   displayFloatingDiv('fpWindowDiv', label,-1,-1,mousePositionX-350,mousePositionY-10,'#DFDFDF',null, 'http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_item_info.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R&amp;node='+ node + '&amp;taskId=CufHLCVJEi2x&autosize=1' + '&amp;targetmode=proteins&noAction=1&search_string_link=1', 'http://stitch.embl.de/images/loading_bigrotation.gif');
   return false;}

function restoreFNButtonMode(event, handler){ 
    var flashNetwork = document.getElementById('StringNetworkFlex'); 
     if(flashNetwork != null && isMouseLeaveOrEnter(event, handler)){ flashNetwork.restoreButtonMode();
}} 
-->
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stitch.embl.de/javascript/newstring_scripts_7018.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stitch.embl.de/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://stitch.embl.de/javascript/basic/basic_js_util_7018.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stitch.embl.de/javascript/basic/basic_ajax_7018.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stitch.embl.de/javascript/basic/basic_floating_div_7018.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stitch.embl.de/javascript/ac_oetags.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function doneLoading() {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'http://stitch.embl.de/images/smallest_logo_p.png';
        }
        //-->
    </script>

<link href='http://stitch.embl.de/css/floatingDiv.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://stitch.embl.de/css/standard_styles_pc.v7266.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body id="stringBodyTag" onclick="hideFDifInside('fpWindowDiv');" onmousedown="hideFDifInside('fpWindowDiv');">
<div style='position:absolute;' class='nodeInfoDivStyle' id='fpWindowDiv' onmouseout='signalFDOnMouseOut(event, this, "fpWindowDiv"); restoreFNButtonMode(event, this); window.status=""; return true;'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'> $("#fpWindowDiv").mouseenter(function() {signalFDOnMouseIn("fpWindowDiv"); });</script><div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
<table style='padding:10px;display:inline-table;' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='visibility:visible;min-width:965px;'>
<tr><td class='img_compact' align='left' valign='middle' style='height:42px; width:42px; white-space:nowrap;' bgcolor='#4060FF'><img src="http://stitch.embl.de/images/small_fillpic_emph_pc.png" width=10 height=5 alt=""><a href='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_input_page.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R'><img src='http://stitch.embl.de/images/logo_still_pc.png' width='36' height='36' alt=''/></a></td><td class='img_compact' align='left' valign='middle' style='height:42px; white-space:nowrap;' bgcolor='#4060FF'><a href='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_input_page.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R' style='text-decoration: none'><span class='top_menu_link_c' style='font-size: 31px;'>&nbsp;STITCH&nbsp;</span><span class='top_menu_link_c' style='font-size: 31px; font-family: FolksLightRegular, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>4.0&nbsp;</span></a></td>
<td class='img_compact' style='text-align:center' style='height:52px; white-space:nowrap;' bgcolor='#4060FF'></td>
<td align='right' valign='top' bgcolor='#4060FF'><div style='margin:0.5em; white-space: nowrap'><a href='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_input_page.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R' class='whitenondecorated'>Input Page</a> | <a href='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_download_page.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R' class='whitenondecorated'>Downloads</a> | <a href='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_info_page.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R' class='whitenondecorated'>Help/Info</a> | <a href='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_my_page.pl?UserId=xrrQRRQ9bQjQ&amp;sessionId=k8xp6Dr4j42R' class='whitenondecorated'>My Data</a>&nbsp;</p><p><form name='navform' id='input_form' action='http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='hidden' name='required_score' value='400'/>
<input type='hidden' name='limit' value='10'/>
<input type='hidden' name='UserId' value='xrrQRRQ9bQjQ'/>
<input type='hidden' name='sessionId' value='k8xp6Dr4j42R'/>
<input type='hidden' name='input_query_species' value='auto_detect'/>
<input type=hidden name='have_user_input' value='2'><input name='identifier' id='single_identifier' value='search' onfocus="onFocusCheckEntry(this, 'search', true);" onblur="onBlurCheckEntry(this, 'search', true);" style='color:grey'/> <script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
document.write ('<a href="#" onclick="document.navform.submit()" class="whitenondecorated">GO!</a>');
-->
</script>
<noscript>
<div><input type='submit' value='GO !' class='stringSubmitButton' style='width: 54px; height: 25px; text-align: center;'/></div>
</noscript>
</form></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='4' valign='top'><script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
<div style='color: red; font-style: italic;'>Warning: your browser appears to have JavaScript disabled.<br/>Some of the features in STITCH may not be available to you<br/></div>
</noscript>
<div style='width:50em;text-align:center;margin:3em;'>
<table style='display:inline-table;'><tr><td><table style='text-align:left;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td class='info_box_title'><div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infoheader.upperright_pc.png') no-repeat right top;">
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infoheader.lowerright_pc.png') no-repeat right bottom;">
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infoheader.upperleft_pc.png') no-repeat left top;">
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infoheader.lowerleft_pc.png') no-repeat left bottom; padding: 8px 12px 7px 12px;">
error ...</div></div></div></div></td></tr>
<tr><td class='info_box_body'>
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infobox.upperright_pc.png') no-repeat right top;">
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infobox.lowerright_pc.png') no-repeat right bottom;">
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infobox.upperleft_pc.png') no-repeat left top;">
<div style="background:url('http://stitch.embl.de/images/infobox.lowerleft_pc.png') no-repeat left bottom; padding: 3px 12px 12px 12px;">
<form action='show_input_page.pl' method='post'>
<div style='text-align:left;'>
<input type='hidden' name='UserId' value='xrrQRRQ9bQjQ'/>
<input type='hidden' name='sessionId' value='k8xp6Dr4j42R'/>
You have not provided any input.
<div style='width:100%;text-align:center;'><input type='submit' value="&nbsp;OK&nbsp;"/></div>
</div>
</form>
</div></div></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posting all of your code makes this pretty tough to answer. Try to narrow it down.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ: looks pretty relevant to me, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Before the 'narrowing' step, yes :)

Comment: Note that `requests` can take a `params` keyword argument that can do the URL encoding *for* you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *URL* already contains GET parameters:

```
stitch_results_url = 'http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl?identifier=802634%20802659&additional_network_nodes=0&chemicalmode=10.5&input_query_species=7955&interactive=yes&internal_call=1&limit=10&minprotchem=1&network_flavor=actions&required_score=400&sessionId=0ZKGxMnojGDg&targetmode=proteins&userId=Ri1Zp7hT9L9G'
```

but the form `action` attribute does not use these parameters:

```
<form action="/cgi/show_network_section.pl" id='standard_parameters' method='post'>
```

Remove these from the URL. Next, don't URL encode everything yourself, leave that to `requests`:

```
import requests

stitch_results_url = 'http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl'
# the custom limit of the interaction shown
interaction_shown_custom_limit = 400
# parameters for active prediction methods
neighborhood = 'off'
gene_fusion = 'off'
co_occurrence = 'off'
co_expression = 'off'
experiments = 'on'
databases = 'on'
textmining = 'on'
# required confidence score
required_confidence = 'high confidence (700)'

# Input parameters we are going to send
parameters = {
    'channel1': neighborhood,
    'channel2': gene_fusion,
    'channel3': co_occurrence,
    'channel4': co_expression,
    'channel5': experiments,
    'channel6': databases,
    'channel7': textmining,
    'required_score':required_confidence,
    'custom_limit':interaction_shown_custom_limit
}

req = requests.post(stitch_results_url, params=parameters)
```

If the form is still not accepted this way, it may be that the JavaScript on that page adds additional information to the form, the form requires the *HTTP Referrer* header to be set, or the site stores additional information in cookies or a cookie-keyed session.

Use a [`Session` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to pass along any cookies the site sets, add a Referrer to the [request headers](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers), and verify with your browser development tools you didn't miss some POST fields.

I note that you are not including the `UserId` and `sessionId` parameters, for example. You'll need to include **all** parameters named in the query portion of the URL for your `POST` request to work.

Comment: The reason that I'm using that URL is because it is what you get after already giving input to the website. The form I want to post to only changes the output shown. So when I use http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl, the website didn't get any input yet and it again says `no input given`

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: the *form* you posted doesn't use that as the URL; see the `action` attribute on the form.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: Much more likely the problem is caused by not including the `sessionId` and `UserId` parameters in your post.